# How can I use mySQL for local file storage?

Tags: c++, mysql, file, local

I really like how mySQL works, and I wish to use mySQL in my program as a simple and efficient way to store the user's data, but that would mean storing it in the computer. My option would be run a mySQL server on the user's computer as it would run on a web server, but what other ways are there. Is there a way to do this without connecting using network? Is there any other kind of system like mysql that would work in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to look at SQLite which is a DB in a single file. Probably easier to use than MySql.

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a special-purpose programming language. MySQL is a relational database management system.
You can use SQL in a lot of database management system for desktop too.
You can see the [list of relational database management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems) how many systems are there.
I would suggest [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) because of its simplicity, portability and for the little space/environment it needs. Best of all that it is under the public domain, so totally free.